# Personal Branding or Service Oriented Freelance Business?

Tags: branding

I'm facing the problem of how do I represent myself? As an individual freelance who does something or as a service for people who are looking for it.

I know that both are related but if your business is online, the domain name, presentation and marketing strategy are completely different. So I would like to know your experience.

Everyday I'm specializing more and more in Web Design + WordPress Development for eCommerce, but still offering services until my name.

**EDIT**

I'm not asking how to brand myself, just what is the best strategy (between two) to offer a service as a freelance or just the service, and why. I don't want to become a brand and I think that what you choose changes completely the strategy that you will follow, so, I would like to know real examples.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make a great deal of sense. *"offer a service as a freelance or just the service"* What would be the difference????

Answer (score 0):

People are looking for solutions to their problems in the first place. They are not looking for "someone".

Comment: Yes, that's the point. I mean to compite as a web designer/developer that does WooCommerce to create Online Stores is the services, but do people look for the task or for the guy that does the task? What inspires more confidence? And so on.

Comment: Yes that's the point. I know that "someone" is not what people are looking for. I want to know whats more effective, offering a service and trying to sell it or being an expert in that service. I know is similar, but for example. I can have kevin.com Expert in WooCommerce. Or woocommercestores.com. What is people looking for? An expert? The services? Do they know it? I'm not asking for the specifics in this case, just for previous experiences from others because it implies a different strategy. **Both appeared after I replied to this one, sorry for dup**